# Clojure UUID - Having trouble creating IDs for defrecords

Tags: clojure, uuid

All I'm trying to do is create an auto-generated UUID for clojure `defrecord`'s when they are created.  I've tried the following:

```
(ns myns
  (:require [clj-uuid :as uuid])

(defrecord Thing [thing-id name])

(defn create-thing
  [name]
  (map->Thing {:thing-id (uuid/v1)
               :name name}))
```

Followed by:

```
(repeat 5 (create-thing "bob"))
```

But I get the **same** UUID created for every `Thing` I create.  Help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm suspicious about using a dedicated lib for this, given how easy it is to do via interop using the built in UUID class that comes with the jvm.

```
(ns myns
  (:import (java.util UUID)))

(defrecord Thing [thing-id name])

(defn create-thing
  [name]
  (map->Thing {:thing-id (UUID/randomUUID)
               :name name}))

;; using repeatedly instead of repeat generates new values,
;; instead of reusing the initial value

(repeatedly 5 #(create-thing "bob"))
```

Comment: I'm fine to use the built-in, but I'm still having the same issue with this. It seems to have something to do with using `(repeat 5 (create-thing "bob"))`

Comment: The issue is `repeat` - `repeat` only evaluates your form once, you want `(repeatedly 5 #(create-thing "bob"))`

Comment: Woo hoo! Worked :) Want to update your answer to this? I'll accept. (The question wasn't the greatest).

Comment: In that case, I think it would make sense to also update the question to show the actual code with the unexpected result while we're at it.

Comment: Done! Thanks again :)